# How do I push a div behind using z-index?

Tags: html, css

How can I push .left-corner slightly behind without disrupting where text begins.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gnjNq/

```
<div class="quick-links-container">
    <div class="left-corner"></div>
    QUICK LINKS
</div>
```

```css
.quick-links-container{
    z-index: 8000;
    right: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    height: 500px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow:0px 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.left-corner{
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow:0px 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    z-index: 7900;
    position: relative;
    left:-10px;
    top: 20px;
}
```

This is what i'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/gnjNq/3/ `Z-index` needed to be a negative value to go behind and remove the `z-index` on the container.

Comment: good call, but I need it to go back even further, past .quick-links-container

Comment: Okay, get rid of the z-index on the container: http://jsfiddle.net/gnjNq/3/ Note that with your shadow, you are going to have a line through the tab part...

Comment: Wonderful! I'll just move the shadow.  Thanks dwreck!

Comment: Have to wait 3 minutes but I'll make sure to do that.

Answer (score 4):

Remove `z-index` for `.quick-links-container` and give `.left-corner` negative `z-index`.

http://jsfiddle.net/gnjNq/4/